# Android: how to detect that status bar opened

Tags: android, statusbar

I am writing an app that needs to know when the status bar opened, and then do something accordingly (for example, fire an intent).
I searched the web exstensively for a way to detect when the status bar opened but i didn't find anything useful.

I had one idea, when I noticed that when the status bar opens, the sensorManager unregister the orientation listener:

> unregisterListener::  Listener=
>   android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@427b63c0

and when the statusbar closes, the sensorManager register that listener:

> registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer
>   delay= 200000 Listener=
>   android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@427b63c0

So i went over the source code and tried to find where this call is made, and which object call it, because if this object can detect the opening of the statusBar so probably i can do it too, but i didnt found the correct place for that call.

I will be glad if anyone can give me the full answer on how to detect when the status bar is being opened, but I would also be satisfied in knowing which object tells the sensorManager to make this register/unregister operations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I am writing an app that needs to know when the status bar opened, and then do something accordingly " -- why?

Comment: I'm trying to write kind of a game that involves a character that smashes when the status bar is sliding down on it.

Comment: Were you detecting this from an Activity, or from a foreground Service?

Comment: Check this for a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509108/how-to-detect-when-the-notification-system-bar-is-opened/53509109#53509109